# Remove order notes checkout field for virtual products only in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

In Woocommerce, I use the following code that disable all checkout fields except the Order Notes and the Additional Information title.

If the cart contains only virtual products, no fields except for First Name, Last Name and email field should be shown.

Code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'simple_virtual_checkout' );
function simple_virtual_checkout( $fields ) {
    $only_virtual_products = true;
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    // Check if there are non-virtual products
    if ( ! $cart_item['data']->is_virtual() ) $only_virtual_products = false; 
    }
    if( $only_virtual_products ) {
    // remove billing fields
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', '__return_false' );

    // remove shipping fields 
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name']);    
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name']);  
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_company']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_city']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_country']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_state']);
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add this line into your function:

```
unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
```

So your code will be:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'simple_virtual_checkout', 20, 1 );
function simple_virtual_checkout( $fields ) {
    $only_virtual_products = true;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Check for non-virtual products
        if ( ! $cart_item['data']->is_virtual() ) 
            $only_virtual_products = false; 
    }

    if( $only_virtual_products ) {
        // remove billing fields
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', '__return_false' );

        // remove shipping fields 
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name']);    
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name']);  
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_company']);
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1']);
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']);
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_city']);
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode']);
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_country']);
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_state']);
        unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_state']);

        // remove order notes
        unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> By default in Woocommerce checkout page, **there is no "Additional Information" title**.
>   So this is certainly related to some customizations made by your theme or a plugin.

Comment: Making the change results in:

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-shipping.php on line 68

From what I can tell there is no change made by the theme for that template. Either way, thank you for your help. Appreciate it.